# Easymock isA vs anyObject

Tags: easymock

What is the difference between

```
EasyMock.isA(String.class)
```

and

```
EasyMock.anyObject(String.class)
```

(Or any other class supplied)

In what situations would would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference is in checking Nulls. The isA returns false when null but anyObject return true for null also.

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class Tests {


    private IInterface createMock(boolean useIsA) {
        IInterface testInstance = createStrictMock(IInterface.class);
        testInstance.testMethod(
                useIsA ? isA(String.class) : anyObject(String.class)
        );
        expectLastCall();
        replay(testInstance);
        return testInstance;
    }
    private void runTest(boolean isACall, boolean isNull) throws Exception {
        IInterface testInstance = createMock(isACall);
        testInstance.testMethod(isNull ? null : "");
        verify(testInstance);
    }
    @Test
    public void testIsAWithString() throws Exception {
        runTest(true, false);
    }
    @Test
    public void testIsAWithNull() throws Exception {
        runTest(true, true);
    }
    @Test
    public void testAnyObjectWithString() throws Exception {
        runTest(false, true);
    }
    @Test
    public void testAnyObjectWithNull() throws Exception {
        runTest(false, false);
    }

    interface IInterface {
        void testMethod(String parameter);
    }
}
```

In the example the testIsAWithNull should fail.

Comment: I think you got your runTest methods backwards in the code, but I get what you're saying! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got really confused with Easymock documentation as EasyMock.isA() in API docs is said to return a Class Object on which it is called,  but Easymock documentation(for isA(Class clazz)) says that

> Matches if the actual value is an instance of the given class, or if it is in instance of a class that extends or implements the given class. Null always return false. Available for objects.

for anyObject() it says

> Matches any value.

You can have a look at Documentation here

- http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations

no specific difference mentioned between these two methods.

Comment: I looked at that but it still wasn't clear to me. Does this mean that anyObject() matches only an instance of that class and isA() will match an instance of that class and any subclasses?

Comment: So then there is no difference?

Comment: Actually as per method Naming conventions isA() should be a method returning a boolean, but only god knows why it returns a instance