# Ignore return value in EasyMock

Tags: junit, junit4, easymock

How do I have EasyMock to test that a method is called and returns a specific type - irrespective of the value viz

```
EasyMock.expect(........).andReturn(String.Type).times(5);
```

I just need to ensure that a method is called x number of times.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either EasyMock.isA(< TypeObj >) or EasyMock.anyObject(< TypeObj >). See below for sample code

`expect(mock.doSomething(...)).andReturn(EasyMock.isA(String.class)).times(5);
replay(mock);
...
verify(mock);`

Check the [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515157/easymock-isa-vs-anyobject) for more details

Answer (score 0):

With EasyMock you have to specify the behaviour of the method call. If the value of the return value doesn't matter then you can return a dummy value. Afterwards you can verify that the mock was called like you expected it to be called.

```
expect(mock.doSomething(...)).andReturn("dummy value").times(5);
replay(mock);
...
verify(mock);
```

Comment: You are right, the verify is needed and that's it. However, his original syntax is preferred. `expect(mock.foo()).andReturn(null).times(5)`